# Why having the same NPM package declared in regular and dev dependency is considered bad?

Tags: node.js, npm

NPM triggers a warning message: `Dependency '...' exists in both dependencies and devDependencies` when my `package.json` explicitly declares the same module in both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`. It suggests that the NPM's developers think it is a wrong way of using NPM.

This is surprising to me since I've always considered it a good practice Doing so means I can change (add / remove / update) my "app dependencies" without breaking my build scripts etc.

Do you know the rational behind this view or do you have examples where it could introduce problems?

Answer (score 4):

`dependencies` and `devDependencies` are both installed into the `node_modules` directory at the top level. If you declare it in both sections, you might declare it at different versions (or conflicting version ranges), which would it impossible for npm to meet both requirements at the same time.

In practice, if you declare it in both sections, npm will pick the version declared in `dependencies`, even if it is older, since this is usually what you meant to happen.

As a corollary: if you update your app dependencies to a version that would break your build scripts, it *will* break your build scripts, and declaring it twice won't help.

Comment: For those who are new to all this, you can fix this by removing the offending items from `devDependencies` in package.json. (Worked for me, anyhow.)